# An activity with two listviews in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, layout, android-listview

**MainAcitivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView list, listYear;
String[] web = {
        "Google Plus",
        "Twitter",
        "Windows",
        "Bing",
        "Itunes",
        "Wordpress",
        "Drupal"
} ;
String[] year = {
        "2012",
        "2013",
        "2014",
        "2015",
        "2016",
        "2017",
        "2018"
} ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, web));
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + web[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    listYear=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listYear);
    listYear.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, year));
    listYear.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + year[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

**layout_activity**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="YEAR" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listYear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="#B29090" >
            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="WEBSITE" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="#B29090" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

*What I want is to display both the activities in a single activity.
The only problem that I am facing up is that it looks like i am not able to show the layout properly because it is showing only the 2nd layout with scroll-bars instead of the scrollview's scrolls*

Comment: tried replacing it ... but still of no use

Comment: just remove the scorllview ...

Comment: are you aware with custom listview ..?

Comment: yeah, i am aware of it

Comment: **1** `fill_parent` is **deprecated**, since API Level **8**. Use `match_parent`. **2** why all this **awful** `layout nesting`?. **3** `ListViews inside Scrollviews` are **evil**!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with your `RelativeLayout` under your `ScrollView`.

Try replacing it with a vertical `LinearLayout` and give its 2 child `LinearLayout` a weight of 1 like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="YEAR" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listYear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="#B29090"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="WEBSITE" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="#B29090"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: it will surely help me out but its of no use

Comment: 'coz i want to implement something like this 
https://camo.githubusercontent.com/bbabd30ab2af2c19854c89b6dc691529806127d9/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f6265776f726b65722f70696e6e65642d73656374696f6e2d6c697374766965772f6d61737465722f73637265656e312e706e67

Comment: Then you'll need to use 1 single custom `ListView` without the `ScrollView`  (coz the scrolling will be present with the listview) and with a logic different than 1 dimensional string array

Comment: but then how would i be creating the sections like in the image i showed u

Comment: It will depend on how you will populate your listview

Answer (score 0):

try this skeleton.. may be it helps you

```
<LinearLayout orintion='vertical'>
   <LinearLayout weight='1'>
      <Listview /> <Other controls>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout weight='1'>
       <Listview /> <Other controls>
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: 'coz i want to implement something like this 
https://camo.githubusercontent.com/bbabd30ab2af2c19854c89b6dc691529806127d9/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f6265776f726b65722f70696e6e65642d73656374696f6e2d6c697374766965772f6d61737465722f73637265656e312e706e67

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/Listbyoperator_listvirtacel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:divider="#ffffff"
            android:background="#C92B2B"
            android:dividerHeight="1px">

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontal"

         android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/Listbyoperator_detaillist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: no....  it wont be of any help 'coz i want to implement something like this 
https://camo.githubusercontent.com/bbabd30ab2af2c19854c89b6dc691529806127d9/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f6265776f726b65722f70696e6e65642d73656374696f6e2d6c697374766965772f6d61737465722f73637265656e312e706e67